# How to avoid blinking form on load

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have many groupbox and datagridview at the `Form 2` but when I proceed to `Form2` it will create blinking screen, that's why it is my problem on how to hide/disable other groupbox and only one would show on form load. 
By the way it is my code :

On form2_load:

```
  grpbox1.Show()
  grpbox2.Hide()
  grpbox3.Hide()
  grpbox4.Hide()
  grpbox5.Hide()
  grpbox6.Hide()
```

By the way any idea on how to prevent this? By the way it is written in `Vb.net`.

Comment: Try `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`...

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, the window is not yet visible when the Load event fires.  That happens right after it, the Shown event is fired to tell you that it happened.  Maybe you are doing something else wrong, but surely using Load for code like this is a bad practice in general, this code belongs in the constructor.  Or just plain in the designer, use the Properties window to set the Visible property.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code to the form constructor that will be run before the form load event:

```
Public Class Form2

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        For Each c In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)
            c.Hide()
        Next

        grpbox1.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```